# Dart Package - How to hide internal methods in public classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I am developing a package on Flutter.

There are I have methods in classes that are useful only for the package itself, and not for the programmer who will import my package, is possible to hide this methods in public classes for further implementation?

I am trying use `@internal` annotation, but I can still see methods marked as internal outside of the package.

Example:

```dart
/// Base abstract class [ImageData]
abstract class ImageData  {
  /// Create [ImageData] instance.
  const ImageData();

  /// Create [ImageData] instance from [dto].
  ///
  /// by converting from [dto.ImageData].
  @internal
  factory ImageData.fromDto(dto.ImageData object) {
    switch (object.type) {
      case dto.ImageData_Type.pathType:
        return PathImageData(path: object.path);
      case dto.ImageData_Type.rawImageType:
        return RawImageData.fromDto(object.rawImage);
      default:
        throw const PluginInvokeException();
    }
  }

  /// Create [dto.ImageData] from current instance.
  @internal
  dto.ImageData toDto();

}
```

and in other inheritors from this `ImageData`

```dart
class RawImageData extends ImageData {
  /// Bytes of image.
  final Uint8List data;

  /// Describe type of [data] content.
  final RawImageDataType type;

  /// Wight of image
  final int width;

  /// Height of image
  final int height;

  /// Create [RawImageData] instance.
  const RawImageData({
    required this.data,
    required this.type,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
  }) : super();

  /// Create [RawImageData] instance from [dto].
  ///
  /// by converting from [dto.RawImage].
  @internal
  factory RawImageData.fromDto(dto.RawImage object) {
    return RawImageData(
      data: Uint8List.fromList(object.raw),
      type: typeFromDtoEnum(object.type),
      width: object.size.width,
      height: object.size.height,
    );
  }

  @override
  @internal
  dto.ImageData toDto() {
    return dto.ImageData(
      type: dto.ImageData_Type.rawImageType,
      rawImage: toDtoRawImage(),
    );
  }

}
```

But I can still see methods marked as internal outside of the package. How do private this methods **only for outside** package namespaces?

Answer (score 3):

Dart identifiers are either:

- Public
- Private to the library if prefixed with an underscore (`_`).

That's it.

Annotations such as `@protected`, `@internal`, etc. provide additional hints to the Dart analyzer.  They are not enforced at compile-time (unless you explicitly make your build system fail on analysis warnings/errors) nor at runtime. (This also is why null-safe Dart needed a new `required` language keyword and could not use the old `@required` annotation.)

Either accept relying on analysis warnings or rename `toDto` to `_toDto` to make it private.  Since private identifiers are private to the Dart *library*, that then would entail either:

- Moving all your code into the same `.dart` file.
- Explicitly declaring a Dart library with `library` and using `part`/`part of` to specify the `.dart` files that compose that library.

Another technique for hiding package-specific identifiers is to make them public but to place them in a `.dart` file internal to the package (with the expectation that clients will not explicitly `import` it).  That's less useful for your case, however.

Comment: It will do private  the methods for my package to, but I asking about how do private this methods only for outside package namespaces.

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin I don't understand. As I said, there is only public and library private.